# Excel date is changed to different date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am trying to import the excel file to mysql database. I have got date and IMEI field in excel to import to database. But while importing to database my date is changd to different date and IMEI no is changed to exponential format. How can I resolve that problem.

here is the picture.
[image: This is my Excel file that i m importing to database.]

[image: This is my database picture after importing the excel file.]

And here is the code.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "portal";


//$exceldata = array();

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

/** Set default timezone (will throw a notice otherwise) */
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');


include 'Classes2/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'])){

// $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
// $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//Checking the file extension


        $file_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $inputFileName = $file_name;
if(is_uploaded_file($inputFileName)){
    //  Read your Excel workbook
    try {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME) 
        . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    //Table used to display the contents of the file
    echo '<center><table style="width:50%;" border=1>';

    //  Get worksheet dimensions
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();


    //  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
    for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
        //  Read a row of data into an array
        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, 
        NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

    //check whether member already exists in database with same email
 $prevQuery = "SELECT id FROM activereport WHERE aIMEI = '".$rowData[0][1]."' ";
          //  $prevResult = $con->query($prevQuery);
            $prevResult = mysqli_query($con,$prevQuery);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($prevResult);

if($count > 0){
                // //update member data      

     $sql = " UPDATE activereport SET modelno= '".$rowData[0][0]."',  dateOfActivation='" . $rowData[0][2] . "' WHERE aIMEI = '" .$rowData[0][1]."' ";

            }
            else{

                $sql = " INSERT INTO activereport (modelno, aIMEI, dateOfActivation) VALUES ('".$rowData[0][0]."','".$rowData[0][1]."','".$rowData[0][2]."')";
                    }

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    $exceldata[] = $rowData[0];
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}

    }


    echo '</table></center>';
        //redirect to the listing page
header("Location: Import_Active_Data.php");        
}

else{
    echo '<p style="color:red;">Please upload valid</p>'; 
}   

} 
?>
```

Comment: Add table DDL to your question.

Comment: Make sure that the datatype on your database column is what it should be. Also, Excel could be passing something completely different to your database, regardless of how it's formatted in the Excel workbook itself.

Comment: Are you saying to make the database table DDL or what. I didn't get it. Can you explain  Bor Laze

Comment: I have used varchar in data base for imei and date for dateOfActivation. Also in excel I have choosed text for imei and custom date format for date like yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason for this behavior could be the way excel stores dates: by counting the days since Jan 1, 1900. if you pass that as an argument to your sql query, it could do weird things.

Try converting the excel date to a string first and pass that to the sql query.

So, I'd change this block:

```
if($count > 0){
            // //update member data      

 $sql = " UPDATE activereport SET modelno= '".$rowData[0][0]."',  dateOfActivation='" . $rowData[0][2] . "' WHERE aIMEI = '" .$rowData[0][1]."' ";

        }
        else{

            $sql = " INSERT INTO activereport (modelno, aIMEI, dateOfActivation) VALUES ('".$rowData[0][0]."','".$rowData[0][1]."','".$rowData[0][2]."')";
                }
```

into this:

```
if($count > 0){
    // Date-to-string conversion start
    $exceldate = $rowData[0][2];
    $phpdate = new DateTime();
    $phpdate->setDate(1899, 12, 30);
    $dateint = new DateInterval("P" . $exceldate . "D");
    $phpdate->add($dateint);
    $datestring = $phpdate->format("Y-m-d");
    // Date-to-string conversion end
            // //update member data      

    $sql = " UPDATE activereport SET modelno= '".$rowData[0][0]."',  dateOfActivation='" . $datestring . "' WHERE aIMEI = '" .$rowData[0][1]."' ";

        }
        else{

            $sql = " INSERT INTO activereport (modelno, aIMEI, dateOfActivation) VALUES ('".$rowData[0][0]."','".$rowData[0][1]."','".$datestring."')";
                }
```

Instead of using the rowData[0][2] directly, this will convert the value of that Excel cell (2017-11-11 = 43050) into a php-string ('2017-11-11'), which you can then pass to the sql query.

Comment: converting excel date to the string works perfectly . I had tried it already. But I want it in date format only not the string format.

Comment: Did you try that in excel or php?

Comment: In both the excel and database.I changed the excel to general and databae to varchar it worked. but after changinig the excel date to date format in database  to date it shows above problem

Comment: That could actually be part of the problem. What mysql expects from you is this:
INSERT INTO activereport (modelno, aIMEI, dateOfActivation) VALUES ('"123456"','"123456"','"2017-01-05"')", but what it's getting is this:INSERT INTO activereport (modelno, aIMEI, dateOfActivation) VALUES ('"123456"','"123456"','"42740"')", because that is the value that is in the Excel cell. In php, you should take that value from the Excel cell, calculate the right date from it and pass the result of that calculation as your parameter.

Comment: Sorry. either i didn't get you or you understood wrong me. Here what i did is INSERT INTO activereport (modelno, aIMEI, dateOfActivation) VALUES ('"123456"','"123456"','"2017-01-05"')" from excel file and in result i get date as 2043-05-00. I didn't get like 4270.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally pressed Enter a bit too early, before I finished typing :)

Comment: no problem @Gabor. Sorry. either i didn't get you or you understood wrong me. Here what i did is INSERT INTO activereport (modelno, aIMEI, dateOfActivation) VALUES ('"123456"','"123456"','"2017-01-05"')" from excel file and in result i get date as 2043-05-00. I didn't get like 4270.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are actually getting that from Excel. I'd be quite surprised if you were getting that. Can you try to print out that sql statement before it is executed?

Comment: I have used PHPExcel to upload my excel file. And here is my sql part as you have asked.

Comment: It's suspicious the date you have in there (2017-11-11) does exactly map to the integer value of 43050 as a number in Excel, which would lead to a date of 2043-05-00 in mysql.

Comment: $sql = " INSERT INTO activereport (modelno, aIMEI, dateOfActivation) VALUES ('".$rowData[0][0]."','".$rowData[0][1]."','".$rowData[0][2]."')";

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean this. I meant what it looks like when the $sql is prepared with all the variables and contains the actual values you are passing in.

Comment: as in the first comment of your "One reason for this behavior could be the way excel stores dates: by counting the days since Jan 1, 1900." the addition of this date to 2017-11-11 gives the 2043-05-00 result . I have already calculated the date. you can try it too.

Comment: Are you saying the error it shows or something else. i didn't get it.

Comment: I'll try to write some code for you which you can try. I'll be back.

Comment: in the above code  $phpdate->setDate(1899, 12, 30); insert 0000-00-00 in date of activation. but when I changed above part to $phpdate->setDate(1899-12-30) it shows result 2135-04-10 for date 2017-11-11

Comment: Would it be an option for you to add one more column to the excel file?

Comment: sorry. it was my mistake. In excel i changed my custom date to excel date and it work. but i wanted to know if i had two column that contain date than I had to changed anything.

Comment: And could you explain the line new DateInterval("P" . $exceldate . "D"); @Gabor

Comment: If you have two columns, you have to do the date-to-string conversion part one more time.

Comment: Explanation: the New DateInterval("P" . $exceldate . "D") creates a new DateInterval objects based on the "P". $exceldate . "D" parameter. "P" means plus, "D" means days. The $exceldate formula contains the numeric value of the date you provide (2017-11-11 = 43050). So, basically you're telling php: take the date of 1899-12-30, and add 43050 days to it to come up with the result of 2017-11-11. This is exactly how Excel works with dates.

Comment: Why it is not supporting the .csv format. While I am trying to send data from .csv date value is 0000-00-00 whichever date format i choose.

Comment: In which line or where do i have to perform date-to-string conversion can you tell please. @Gabor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145304/discussion-between-gabor-and-sushank-pokharel).

Comment: Ok friend let's discuss in chat.